# Multiple modules not found during webpack build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack

I have a problem with webpack in my react app. My project structure is like below:

```
- root
-- app
--- src
---- App.tsx
---- index.tsx
--- package.json
--- assets
---- styles
----- main.css
--- scripts
---- webpack
----- webpack.dev.js
--- public
---- index.html
```

Can someone tell me why, I've got a many of errors like below during webpack build?

```
ERROR in ./src/features/app/settings/AppSettingsDetailsPage.tsx 29:0-43 
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'src/store/store' in 'C:\Users\some\Desktop\some\some\app\src\features\app\settings'
```

example of using import in `AppSettingsDetailsPage`

```
import { dispatch } from "src/store/store";
```

Here is full of my webpack configuration, It's my first journey with webpack :(

Thanks for any help!

webpack.common.js

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  target: 'web',
  entry: {
    app: './src/index.ts',
  },
  output: {
    clean: true,
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../dist'),
    filename: '[name].[contenthash].js',
    publicPath: 'dist/',
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.json', '.svg'],
    symlinks: false,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        exclude: /index.html/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'html-loader',
            options: {
              sources: false,
              minimize: {
                removeComments: false,
                collapseWhitespace: false,
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      }
    ],
  },
};
```

webpack.dev.js

```
'use strict';

const ESLintPlugin = require('eslint-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const path = require('path');
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');

const common = require('./webpack.common.js');

module.exports = (env = {}) =>
  merge(common, {
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    mode: 'development',
    entry: "./src/index.tsx",
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.tsx?$/,
          use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              cacheDirectory: true,
              cacheCompression: false,
            },
          },
          exclude: /node_modules/,
        },
      ],
    },
    plugins: [
      new ESLintPlugin({
        lintDirtyModulesOnly: true,
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx'],
      }),
      new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: '[name].[contenthash].css',
      }),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../public/index.html'),
        template: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../public/index.html'),
        inject: false,
        chunksSortMode: 'none'
      })
    ],
  });
```

Comment: Hello, may I ask for some clarification because I don't really understand your import. In general, there is no need for imports to specify the /src/ usually, but perhaps you have a specific tsconfig or package.json configuration to change the source folder ?  . Technically there, webpack takes what is in your "entry" and put it in the /dist folder. and with your build right now, there is probably no src in the dist folder right ? So webpack cannot resolve the import, because there is no such thing as /src/store/store in dist.

Comment: Just remember, the relative path in /dist has to be the same as your source folder (by default it is src). But I agree, webpack is super useful, but you'll drown in configurations ^^